# Не отображаются текстуры простого куба

Tags: java, opengl

Я разрабатываю программу с использованием lvjgl и lvjgui. 
При попытке отобразить 2D текстуры проблем нет, но когда я пытаюсь отобразить 3D куб у меня отображаются не все текстура. 
Вот код рендера:

```
  @Override
    public void render(Context context) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
       // glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(0f, 0f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);

        glColor3f(1, 0, 1);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f,0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);

        glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);


        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);

        glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);

        glEnd();
        if(rotate)
            glRotatef(0.01f,0.0f,0.5f,0.0f);

    }
```

Перед рендером выполняется следующее:

```
public RenderingCallback() {
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        glClearDepth(0.5f);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
        glRotatef(20f,0.5f,0.0f,0.0f);
    }
```

Сам куб выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Видео](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UQP69Mm0XSbrb45kwRnMzA5cviPjAmtX/view?usp=sharing) для наглядности видео

Как видно, синий цвет вообще не отображается, а некоторые текстура накладываются друг на друга. Если убрать одну из сторон синяя появляется. Как можно решить данную проблему? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @extrn , если я вас правильно понял, то я написал этот код выше "Вот код рендера:" 
Больше собственно и ничего нет, только инициализация окна: https://pastebin.com/JLBsmEBS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мою проблему решили на англоязычном [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669115/simple-cube-textures-not-displaying/59670179#59670179)

Я добавил

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

в `render(Context context)` вместо `public RenderingCallback()` и проблема решилась